# Помогите вывести log в форму(пробросить из одного класса в другой)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Хочу написать программу для вк. Никак не получается пробросить лог в форму. По разному пробовал уже, но все время ругается на то, что `Form1.richTextBox1.Text` недоступен из за уровня защиты. Вот кусочки кода, если нужно могу скинуть полностью:

Form1.cs

```
public static void log(string text)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = text;
}
```

VkAuth.cs

```
string done = net.Get(String.Format("https://login.vk.com/?act=login&email={0}&pass={1}&lg_h={2}", login, pass, pars)).ToString();

int status = CheckAuth(done);//Запрос формируется заново?
if (status == 1) // если всё успешно
{
    Form1.log("Авторизация прошла успешно");
}
if (status == 2) // если аккаунт заблокирован
{
    Form1.log("Аккаунт заблокирован");
}
if (status == 3) //Проверка валидности данных
{
    Form1.log("Проверьте введенные данные");
}
```

Comment: А почему у вас метод `log()` объявлен статическим?

Comment: Если у Вас форма единственная, то организуйте синглтон и обращайтесь к нему через статический метод.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать синглтон, если форма(экземпляр) одна на проект и обращаться к форме через этот синглтон по статическим методам или свойствам.

---

Инициализация синглтона

```
public partial class MyForm : Form 
{
  public static MyForm LastInstance {get; protected set;}
  public MyForm()
  { 
    ...
    LastInstance = this;
  }
  //Если текстбокс объявлен как защищенный 
  public static SetTextLog(string text)
  { 
    LastInstance.ТекстБокс.Text = text;
  }
}
```

Вызов метода синглтона

```
//Если текстбокс объявлен как защищенный 
MyForm.SetTextLog("Какая-то строчка");
//Если текстбокс публичный
MyForm.LastInstance.ТекстБокс.Text = "Какая-то строчка";
```

Answer (score 0):

Из статического метода нет доступа к нестатическим элементам класса, каковым элементам и является ваш richTextBox. Сделайте event в вашем окне VkAuth, а в Form1 просто подписывайте на него нестатическую функцию (ИМХО). Либо передавайте каким либо другим образом нужную вам информацию (например через поле).

Form1.cs

```
private log(string txt) { richTextBox1.Text = txt; }   

VkAuth authWnd = new VkAuth();
authWnd.NewMessage += log;
authWnd.Show();
```

VkAuth.cs

```
public event Action<string> NewMessage;

public VkAuth()
{
    ...
    NewMessage += new delegate(string) {};
}

//Какая то функция
{
    string done = net.Get(String.Format("https://login.vk.com/?act=login&email={0}&pass={1}&lg_h={2}", login, pass, pars)).ToString();

    int status = CheckAuth(done);//Запрос формируется заново?
    if (status == 1) // если всё успешно
    {
        NewMessage("Авторизация прошла успешно");
    }
    if (status == 2) // если аккаунт заблокирован
    {
        NewMessage("Аккаунт заблокирован");
    }
    if (status == 3) //Проверка валидности данных
    {
        NewMessage("Проверьте введенные данные");
    }
}
```

Comment: можно воспользоватся `NewMessage?.Invoke("Аккаунт заблокирован")` и не объявлять пустой делегат в конструкторе

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, в принципе да, но я как то старался проще для новичка сделать.